# Text is not aligning vertically with a Switch in a Row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to have a piece of text allign vertically to a Switch in a Row in my app but it's not alligning straight.

```
    Row (
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .size(48.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.round_up_tip),
            //modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline()
        )

        Switch(
            checked = roundUp,
            onCheckedChange = onRoundUpChanged,
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.End)
        )
    }
```

This is what is currently happening on my test device:

[image: current]

The only half solution I found so far was to use `alignByBaseline()` modifier on the Text but that doesn't quite fully center it either as you can see:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have to change `modifier` to `Modifier` on the Switch, because I tried it and they are aligned.

Comment: @MatteoZattera that's exactly what it was, after changing it to Modifier and adding fillMaxHeight() the issue was solved, thank you  :)